# Row sums of matrix over/under diagonal

Tags: r, matrix, diagonal, rowsum

I want to calculate row/col sums for upper/lower triangle matrix (with diagonal). Example:

```
m <- matrix(1:9, nrow=3)
#result:
upperRowSums(m)
## [1] 12 13 9
lowerRowSums(m)
## [1] 1 7 18
```

I know that this could be done with simple `for` loop, but I want to avoid this. I'm looking for pure `R` solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way:

```
rowSums(m * upper.tri(m, diag=TRUE))
#[1] 12 13  9
```

Comment: For those not sure what the `T` references, in expanded form this is: `rowSums(m * upper.tri(m,diag=TRUE))`